# Playing native Windows sounds in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

In there any way to play Windows native sounds using Inno Setup?

For example I'm showing a custom message box, and I need to play Windows warning/info/error sound before showing that message. Any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`PlaySound` WinAPI function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85)):

```pascal
const
  SND_ASYNC = $0001;
  SND_ALIAS = $00010000; 

function PlaySound(pszSound: string; hmod: THandle; fdwSound: DWORD): BOOL;
  external 'PlaySoundW@Winmm.dll stdcall';
```

Use it like:

```pascal
PlaySound('SystemQuestion', 0, SND_ALIAS or SND_ASYNC);
```

For list of standard sound aliases, see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/using-playsound-to-play-system-sounds

Comment: thank you man, you always help me with inno setup problems, you are great :)